# "confer" ("cf.") vs "see also"

Tags: semantics, academia

I used to think that "confer" ("cf.") is to be used to refer to another source discussing the same issue, or making the same argument etc. But it seems some (many?) people use it instead of "see also", so that the additional source discusses something else that is merely related.

So, which should I use when? Also, are there other, similar expressions used in academic writing which I might want to consider?

Comment: cf. is usually an invitation to the reader to 'compare' with another source; which may not even have the same subject matter, let alone agree.  (derived from Latin: 'conferre').  So it's not that different from 'see also' in current usage.  'See', on the other hand, does suggest a supporting citation.

Comment: ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_signal )

Comment: A couple of similar abbreviations used are: **q.v.** _quod vide_ ‘which see’, used to direct the reader to a named or numbered section in the same work (e.g., “I discuss this further in chapter six, q.v.”); and **s.v.** _sub voce/verbo_ ‘under the voice/word’, used to refer to dictionary entries and similar ‘entry-like headings’ (e.g., “This agrees with the definition given by the OED s.v. _anathema_”). The former is relatively common in academic writing especially; the latter is relatively uncommon everywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

comment reposted as an answer, extracted and edited for brevity from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_signal :

Signals that indicate support:

[no signal] - a simple citation of another source.

'e.g' (exempli gratia) = 'for example'.

'accord' is used to introduce other supporting sources to follow up previous citations.

'see' indicates that the cited authority clearly supports, but does not directly state, the proposition.

'see also' indicates additional material that supports the proposition, less directly than 'see' or 'accord'.

'cf.' (Latin 'confer') = 'compare': points to a different proposition, but one sufficiently analogous to lend support.

There are other signals which suggest that cited sources contain background material, or contradiction.

Comment: Please add the highlights of the article to your answer: otherwise this will become valueless if Wikipedia moves, deletes or heavily edits that article.

Comment: Yes sorry, was being lazy. Now edited.